# jquery hover last element fails

Tags: jquery, hover, element

I have several divs that animate when passing the mouse:

```
<div class="ivideo">
<a href="#">
<img src="default01.jpg" width="190" height="142" />                
</a>
</div>

<div class="ivideo">
<a href="#">
<img src="default02.jpg" width="190" height="142" />                
</a>
</div>

<div class="ivideo">
<a href="#">
<img src="default03.jpg" width="190" height="142" />                
</a>
</div>
```

I use hoverIntent jquery plugin for this case:

```
var configVideo = {
                sensitivity: 3,
                interval: 100,
                over: videoOver,
                timeout: 200,
                out: videoOut
            };

    $(".ivideo").hoverIntent( configVideo );

    function videoOver(){
        $('img',this).animate({ 
                opacity: 0.3
            }, 100 );

            $('<span><\/span>').appendTo($('a',this));
            $('span',this).fadeIn(100);

    }

    function videoOut(){
            $('img',this).animate({ 
                opacity: 1
            }, 100 );

            $('span',this).fadeOut(100 ,function() {$(this).remove()});
    }
```

My problem is that all elements react well (when I use the mouse quickly) but the last div will always fail (always get stuck in the mouseout event)

What would be my mistake? I hope your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/fQ2CY/5/)

Actually all elements will fail but you tested them fast one after the other and stopped with the mouse when you where finished, right?
The problem is that a div will automatically have a width of 100% so there is no way to go out of it of you don't go down or out of the document with your mouse.
Thats why you need to set a fixed width or use another element.